# ¿Cómo restringir dos fechas?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

estoy haciendo un trabajo en un modulo de compras y al registrar esta debo ingresar la fecha de la compra y posterior a ello si la compra es a crédito ingresar la fecha limite de pago.

Lo que necesito es que la fecha limite de pago no pueda ser inferior a la de la fecha de compra, que no permita ni siquiera hacer clic sobre una fecha anterior.

adjunto el código.

```
        $('#FechaInicio').datepicker({
            language: 'es',
            autoclose: true,
        });

        $('#FechaFin').datepicker({
            language: 'es',
            autoclose: true
        });
```

en la vista tengo esto.

```
<input class="form-control" id="FechaInicio" name="total" ng-model="Compra.FECHA_COMPRA" />
<input class="form-control" id="FechaFin" ng-model="Compra.FECHA_LIMITEPAGO" />
```

Comment: Has de mostrar lo que has intentado. Prueba a hacerlo y si tienes fallos concretos preguntalos aqui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seleccionas el `mindate` en `Dateapicker`:

```
        $('#FechaInicio').datepicker({
                    ...,
                    minDate:0 //dia actual
                    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                      var date2 = $('#FechaInicio').datepicker('getDate');
                      date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);
                      $( "#FechaFin" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", date2);
                    window.setTimeout(function()    {$('#FechaFin').datepicker('show')},50);            
                  }
    });

$('#FechaFin').datepicker({
                ...
});
```

Asi el segundo datepicker solo puede seleccionar fechas al menos un día posterior al día seleccionado en el primero. Para ello seteas la fecha mínima del segundo datepicker en función del primero en el momento de cerrarlo, que es cuando ya tiene una fecha seleccionada. La última línea es para mostrar el segundo tras cerrar el primero, puedes comentarla sino es lo que quieres.